# About bootstrap-sass version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm

About bootstrap-sass version:

I am using Laravel 5.2,
in `package.json`,
the latest version of `bootstrap-sass` on nmpjs.com is 3.3.6,
but I am using Bootstrap 4,
how to get  Bootstrap 4 's version?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following package.json to get the current alpha version of Bootstrap 4.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    }
}
```

You can also add repositories from GitHub by pointing directly to the repository. See the NPM documentation - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository

Example: `"bootstrap": "twbs/bootstrap#v4-dev"`

GitHub repositories also can be added with `npm install` as documented - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Example: `npm install twbs/bootstrap#v4-dev`